# How do I use an enum in an `if` statement when I don't care what value it contains?

Tags: if-statement, enums, rust

I have an enum:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B(usize),
}
```

I can use it in `if` statements involving other logic like `baz`:

```
fn bar(foo: &Foo, baz: bool) {
    if foo == &Foo::B(3) || baz {
        println!("Do stuff")
    }
}
```

However, this won't compile:

```
fn bar(foo: &Foo, baz: bool) {
    if foo == &Foo::B(_) || baz {
        println!("Do stuff")
    }
}
```

How do I use it in an `if` statement when I don't care what value `B` contains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier to use a `match` in this case:

```
fn do_stuff() {
    println!("Do stuff")
}

fn bar(foo: &Foo, baz: bool) {
    match foo {
        &Foo::B(_) => do_stuff(),
        _ => {
            if baz {
                do_stuff();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively with an `if let`:

```
fn bar(foo: &Foo, baz: bool) {
    if let &Foo::B(_) = foo {
        do_stuff();
    } else {
        if baz {
            do_stuff();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you can pull it all into a single condition easily, which makes you repeat `do_stuff` unfortunately.

Comment: You can deduplicate `do_stuff()` by matching against `(foo, baz)`: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=32d81133f7131c508c0c8689329e22d0&version=stable). Although you may or may not consider that more maintainable.

Comment: Is there any reason why `if foo == &Foo::B(_) || baz {` could not be added to the language sometime in the future?

Comment: @HiDefender There is an issue for that: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/935

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html):

```
use std::mem::discriminant;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Foo {
    A,
    B(usize),
}

fn main() {
    let to_test = Foo::B(123);
    let some_bool = true;

    if discriminant(&to_test) == discriminant(&Foo::B(0)) && some_bool {
        println!("Do stuff");
    }
}
```

If you have to test this a lot, I advice you to implement a method for it:

```
impl Foo {
    fn is_b(&self) -> bool {
        discriminant(self) == discriminant(&Foo::B(0))
    }
}
```